# Possible directions for directional derivative

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

In which directions at the point (2,0) does the function $f(x,y)=xy$ have a rate of change of -1?

$$D_a⃗f(2,0) = ∇f(2,0)⋅a⃗ $$
$$-1 = ||(0,2)|| ||a⃗||cos(θ)$$
$$-1 = (2)(1)cos(θ)$$
$$-1/2 = cos(θ)$$
$$θ = 2π/3,4π/3$$

Is this answer correct, in that there are two angles 2π/3 and 4π/3 radians in the counter-clockwise direction from the gradient vector at point (2,0) at which the function has a rate of change of -1?

Is this the case for all functions in R3, that they always have two angles for each derivative value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with directional derivatives. As you've noted, it's an observation about the dot product. Fixing $\vec x$ and the length of $\vec a$, then $\vec x\cdot\vec a$ will be the same for two positions of $\vec a$: Once you find one, reflecting across the line spanned by $\vec x$ gives you another. And those are the only ones.

(The simplest case to see is dot product $0$. Then you get the two vectors — in your case of length $1$ — orthogonal to $\vec x$.)

This is all about two dimensions. In three dimensions, you get a cone when you rotate $\vec a$ around the axis spanned by $\vec x$, and the tip of that vector traces out a circle. And so on in higher dimensions.